# Unsupported tarball from ... File located at "result" is a symbolic link to absolute path

Tags: haskell-stack, nix

I used cachix for nix if it has any bearing, and reinstalled stack, too. The repo in question is at: https://github.com/NorfairKing/tickler

```
[jk@jk tickler]$ stack build
Cloning 85ee8a577fb576e2dd7643bf248ff8fbbe9598ec from git@github.com:NorfairKing/pretty-relative-time.git
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jk/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Unsupported tarball from /tmp/with-repo-archive30826/foo.tar: File located at "result" is a symbolic link to absolute path /nix/store/j0l1f389pmxdazxr0h0ax8v6c8ln578h-pretty-relative-time-0.0.0.0
```

Running nix build:

```
[jk@jk tickler]$ nix build
error: Please be informed that this pseudo-package is not the only part of
Nixpkgs that fails to evaluate. You should not evaluate entire Nixpkgs
without some special measures to handle failing packages, like those taken
by Hydra.
```

```
let
  pkgsv = import (import ./nix/nixpkgs.nix);
  pkgs = pkgsv {};
  intray-version = import ./nix/intray-version.nix;
  intray-repo = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub intray-version;
  intray-overlay = import (intray-repo + "/nix/overlay.nix");
  validity-version = import (intray-repo + "/nix/validity-version.nix");
  validity-overlay = import (pkgs.fetchFromGitHub validity-version + "/nix/overlay.nix");
in pkgsv {
  overlays = [ validity-overlay intray-overlay (import ./nix/overlay.nix) ];
  config.allowUnfree = true;
}
```

Comment: Might help to do `stack build -v`.

Comment: 2019-06-29 20:54:17.201006: [error] Unsupported tarball from /tmp/with-repo-archive4145/foo.tar: File located at "result" is a symbolic link to absolute path /nix/store/j0l1f389pmxdazxr0h0ax8v6c8ln578h-pretty-relative-time-0.0.0.0

Comment: Your nix file would be useful too. (default.nix ?)

Comment: added repo link, and default.nix in body. It's monorepo, with dependency on other repos (gitmodules)

Comment: Might have more luck if you posted this as in issue? It seems there is a lot going on - this might be difficult to debug as is. A MCVE(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be ideal.

Comment: Possibly it's fixed here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/4581 you could try upgrading your stack version

Comment: It worked a while back, and 2.1.1 is latest. I suppose that the nix package raising the error is garbage, although I don't think it was added after the repo last worked. I'll probably have to look into just deleting any code associated with it.